# STM32 2 PWM Generation with phase difference using TIM1 and TIM2. TIM2 PWM does not turn on properly when i stop it and restart

Tags: timer, stm32, delay, pwm, phase

I can generate 2 pwm signals with phase difference between them, but when I stop and restart, TIM2 PWM turn on with %100 Duty Cycle.

I use Internal Triggering System to generate delay between to PWM.
1.PWM → TIM1 CH1
Output Compare No Output → TIM1 CH2
2.PWM → TIM2 CH1

I communicate with STM32 via UART using C# windows form application. For example: If I send 0x50, PWMs are turned on, if I send 0x51, PWMs are turned off.

start code:

```
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIM_OC_Start(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
```

stop code:

```
`HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
HAL_TIM_OC_Stop(&htim1, TIM_CHANNEL_2);
HAL_TIM_PWM_Stop(&htim2, TIM_CHANNEL_1);`
```

- When I run start code, 2 PWM turn on properly
- When I run stop code, 2 PWM turn off properly
- When I run start code **again**, Firs PWM (master) turn on properly, Second PWM (Slave) turns on with %100 Duty Cycle

Anyone who can help?

Comment: Check timer registers after you start the first time and after you start the second time. Some timer configuration has to differ. Maybe Stop() disables some timer config that Start() doesn't apply. Try to reinitialize the timers entirely before you Start the second time. They do have some initialization, right? If so, try initializing again and see if it starts to work again. Then reinitialize fewer and fewer configs, until it stops working again. Maybe this way could also work.

Comment: Thanks for advice but it did not work. I have tried using some init functions before PWM_Start() and also some deinit functions before PWM_Stop().

Comment: So compare timer registers after you start the first time and the second time. There is bound to be a mismatch, otherwise it would work.

Comment: Thanks! When i write __HAL_TIM_ENABLE() and __HAL_TIM_DISABLE() before start code stop code, Problem is solved. However, adding phase difference with 'Output Compare No Output TIM1 CH2' does not work when i use __HAL_TIM_ENABLE() and DISABLE :/

Comment: Hi Ilya! Do you have any advice or idea? :)

Comment: As I said, the answers lie in comparing timer register states at different moments. They should be very similar in all settings at similar moments of operation (after being started or after being stopped).  Get timer register screenshots at different moments, compare them number by number. It's not easy and handy, but the answer is definitely in there, the registers are a "control panel". Also, good moment to start looking at the registers. Nothing advances your knowledge like figuring out why something doesn't work. I don't have any easy and ready solutions, I have only so much info.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I want to generate two PWM signals shifted by an adjustable delay. I found the answer in this part of the reference manual of the STM32H723/733, STM32H725/735 "43.3.10 Output compare mode". In this part, I have seen :

"The output pin can keep its level (OCXM=0000), be set active (OCxM=0001), be set inactive (OCxM=0010) or can toggle (OCxM=0011) on match."

In my project, made with CubeMX, I have set up "active level on match", but it must be "toggle on match" (TIM_OCMODE_TOGGLE in code for sConfigOC.OCMode).

My hypothesis is that on the first capture of the OC2REF for the slave timer, the output pin stays always high so when we restart the timer we cannot trigger, because the signal is high. I'm not sure if it is the correct understanding, but it works for me !

To generate this type of signal I watched this video from ST : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QMAgD9SS5_E

But, they used the mode "Active level on match".

I know you already solved your problem, but I answer here if someone  facing the problem ^^

[Here a screen from my MX configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bVO3.png)

Regards.